# C# -How to send a URL as the ID for a GET method of a Web.Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I send a GET request where the ID I'm sending is a URL?

Ie, I'm calling the following (which obviously doesn't work) in order to see if the URL I'm sending is already in my database.

http://myserver.com/api/checkurl/http://www.urltocheck.com.au/people/112

My client side code is:

```
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://myserver.com/api/checkurl",  urlToCheck).Result;
```

And on the API side:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/checkurl/{url}")]
public HttpResponseMessage CheckURLExistsApi(string url)
{
    var url = db.URLS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Url == url);
    if (url != null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);         }

    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

Is there a way I should be encapsulating my url string? Or should I be using a POST instead of a GET and sending a dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: it needs to be [URL Encoded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Should be `http://myserver.com/api/checkurl/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urltocheck.com.au/people/112`

Comment: Well, that's an easy fix...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments suggested to URL encode, but I ran into problems with the query string being potentially dangerous, and wasn't comfortable removing that protection site wide through the web.config.

So what i ended up doing is creating a model to hold my URL, and using the PostAsJson method to POST it, and get the HTTP status code for evaluation.

Comment: As an option, you could encrypt `URL` (e.g. as Base64 or similar) and pass it as encrypted string value